# measure of variance of a dataset without taking number of samples in account

Tags: variance, dataset

i am looking for a measure of variance of a dataset that doesn't get affected by the number of samples but explains the spreading of the values . Do you have anything in mind ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a simple indicator such as the inter-quartile range?  Nothing beats the good ol' box plot for a visual representation of spread in a data set.  It will take the middle 50% of your sorted values by dividing your data set into quartiles and calculate Q3-Q1.  It's as valid a measure of variability and its not affected by the number of samples and it'll exclude most outliers.